# Jquery `.on()` get 2nd paramater as DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Code (in CoffeeScript):

```
$shoppingCartItems.on 'click', $('a.data-trash'), ->
  if confirm 'Remove this item?'
    console.log $this
    $.post '/delete-cart-item',
      id: $this.attr 'data-cart-id'
    .done (e) ->
      alert e.message
      if e.type is 'success'
        $this.remove()
        $itemNumber.text e.data.countItems + ' item(s) - ' + e.data.total
        $subTotal.text e.data.sub_total
        $vat.text e.data.vat
        $total.text e.data.total
      return
    .fail (xhr, status, e) ->
      alert xhr.responseText
      return
  false
```

Expected result:

> `$this will be clicked element of $('a.data-trash')`

Reality:

> `$this equal to $shoppingCartItems.`

**Q:**

How can I get `$this` equal to the expected result?

Comment: Are you trying to set up a delegated event handler on elements that match `'a.data-trash'`? Because perhaps I'm just confused by the CoffeeScript syntax, but you seem to be passing `$('a.data-trash')` as the *data* argument to `.on()`, which means jQuery then passes that object back in `event.data`, while `this` is going to be `$shoppingCartItems`. If you want that argument to be used as a selector it needs to be a string, not an object.

Comment: I concur with @nnnnnn. To successfully delegate, the second arg of `.on()` must be a jQuery selector, not a jQuery collection.

Comment: And unless coffeescript works in some dark mysterious way, you will need `var $this = $(this);` statement somewhere.

Comment: @nnnnnn: teah i should've removed the $(), it works now

Comment: @Roamer-1888: it is, my bad